# Does this condition implies convexity?

Tags: analysis

Let $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined on an interval $I$ such that
$$
f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3) \leq t_1 f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2)+t_3f(x_3)
$$
for all $t_1,t_2,t_3>0$ such that $t_1+t_2+t_3=1$ and all $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in I$.

Is $f$ convex, that is

$$
f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2) \leq t_1 f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2)
$$
for all $t_1,t_2>0$ such that $t_1+t_2=1$ and all $x_1,x_2 \in I$  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just choose $x_2=x_3$. 
Detailed answer: fix any $0<\lambda<1$ and $x_1,x_2\in I$. Put $t_2=t_3:=\frac{\lambda}{2}$ and $t_1:=1-\lambda$. Your hypothesis says that
$$f\left((1-\lambda) x_1+\frac{\lambda}{2} x_2+\frac{\lambda}{2} x_2\right)\le (1-\lambda) f(x_1)+\frac{\lambda}{2}f(x_2)+\frac{\lambda}{2}f(x_2) $$
i.e. $f((1-\lambda) x_1+\lambda x_2)\le (1-\lambda)f(x_1)+\lambda f(x_2)$. 
Since $x_1,x_2,\lambda$ are arbitrary, this tells you that $f$ is convex.